# validation form in controllers ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

im a new for ruby on rails. i have a question. is it posible to make a validation form into controllers. im learning that every validation is set in model but not in controllers.

i made simple form like this

```
<%= form_for :post, url: email_path  do |f| %>
      <dl class="cf">
        <dt class="required">Nama</dt>
        <dd><%= f.text_field(:name,  {:class => 'input_text full'}) %></dd>
      </dl>
      <dl class="cf">
        <dt class="required">nama Perusahaan</dt>
        <dd><%= f.text_field(:company, {:class => 'input_text full'}) %></dd>
      </dl>
      <dl class="cf">
        <dt class="required">nomor telepon</dt>
        <dd><%= f.text_field(:tel, {:class => 'input_text tel'}) %></dd>
      </dl>
      <dl class="cf">
        <dt class="required">alamat email</dt>
        <dd><%= f.text_field(:email, {:class => 'input_text email'}) %></dd>
      </dl>
      <dl class="cf">
        <dt class="">pertanyaan / komentar</dt>
        <dd><%= f.text_area(:commant, {:class => 'textarea'}) %></dd>
      </dl>
      <ul class="form_btn cf">
        <li class="submit"><%= f.submit(t('.ultra_tech_form_title').html_safe) %></li>
      </ul>

      <% end %>
```

the display is this

[image]

but if the required (*) is empty, it will display like this

[image]

this form is directly send email. so i need to set validation. how do i to set this.

Answer (score 3):

You do not put validations in controllers, you put validations in your models. I suggest that you read [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html). Your code needs to look like this:

`post.rb`

```
validates :name, :email, presence: true
```

Additionally, if you use [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) gem you will get those `*` symbols by the required fields by default. All you need to do is to add a validation rule to the attribute of your model.

If you want to send an email automatically after the Post is created, I suggest that you read [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html) and [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html). Basically, what you need to pay attention to is to separate the process of creating a Post from the process of sending an email, therefore, what I advise you to do is to create a job which will send an email in the background. To sum up, frist you want to validate your `post` model and, when it's valid, you want to run a background job, which would send an email. I hope this makes sense to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create validations in the model, and then in the controller, define what the error is, and then render it in the view.

For example, in your model, do something like:

```
validates :name, presence: true
```

In the controller, send error message to:

```
@error = @post.errors.full_message
```

In the view, you can do something like:

```
<% if !@error.nil? %> 
  <span> <%= @error. %> </span>
<% end %>
```

Comment: thank you for your support. but in this form. there is no model for that.

Comment: Do you have a post.rb?

Comment: Yes. Basically, the model is a class that talks to the database and validates the data. You can create the model by running rails g model Post. You will see a migration file where you will be able to add the fields (name, email etc) and then you can run rake db:migrate to perform the migration. 
https://www.culttt.com/2015/09/30/creating-your-first-ruby-on-rails-model/